# Type or namespace 'ProxyManager' does not exist in the namespace 'Sitecore.Data.Proxies'

Tags: powershell-extensions

I've recently downloaded the source codes for Sitecore Powershell Extensions from GitHub and I've updated the Sitecore references to use the Sitecore 9 Nuget references.  After doing so, I've found that there are build errors because of code that no longer seems to be available in Sitecore 9.

Specifically, in the Cognifide.Powershell project, `PsSitecoreItemProvider.cs`, line 566, it is referring to `ProxyManager`, however it looks like `Sitecore.Data.Proxies` no longer has `ProxyManager` in Sitecore 9.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this an issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are compiling against 9.x?

Comment: Because it's for a SC9 project.  I've done a DotPeek on the Cognifide DLL from the package on the marketplace to see what's going on in there, and it's referring to ProxyManager, which is from the 8.x DLL, so I'm confused as to how that can work when running it in a 9.x environment (which doesn't have ProxyManager).

Comment: My understanding from members in the community is that 4.7.2 operates fine with Sitecore 9. A future version may come with a version specific dll to address these types of compile errors. You can see that it was previously done for v7 and v8. It should work because if a class is never called it never errors.

Comment: After a closer inspection, I would expect this to error when moving media items.

Comment: Exactly.  So, strictly speaking, it's not 100% compatible with Sitecore 9.x.

Comment: Reported this as a defect. Not sure any module will be 100%, but SPE sure comes close! https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/issues/1015

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything wrong.

ProxyManager, SqlServerProxyDataProvider, SqlProxyDataProvider, ProxyDisabler  and many proxy related classes have been deprecated in Sitecore 9.

There is no replacement for them in Sitecore 9.

For more details about ProxyDisabler, see [this post](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2018/01/22/in-sitecore-9-the-proxydisabler-have-been-retired-completely/).